# Hacer modales con React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal, frontend, usestate

Estoy creando un modal con React y estoy teniendo un problema para poder ejecutarlo en una app que es una lista de regalos. Mi enfoque fue crear un custom hook para poder gestionar todos los estados de los modales que la app requiera hoy y en el futuro. Ahora, cuando actualizo el estado de la app (comprobado que el estado se actualiza haciendo correr un useEffect con un console log del estado) el modal no se renderiza cuando debería hacerlo. Voy a compartir el código de App.jsx, useModal.js y useGifts.js, que es el hook que se encarga de gestionar los regalos.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

App.jsx

```
export function App(){
    const {gifts, addGift, deleteGift, deleteAllGifts}=useGifts();
    const {isOpen, toggle}=useModal();
    const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const gift=e.target[0].value;
        addGift(gift);
        e.target[0].value=""
    }
    return (
        <main>
            <section className="giftsContainer">
                <h1>Regalos</h1>
                <ul>
                    {gifts.map(el=>{
                        return (
                            <article key={el}>
                                <li>
                                    <p>{el}</p>
                                </li>
                                <button className="deleteButton" onClick={()=>deleteGift(el)}><IconTrash /></button>
                            </article>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingresá tu regalo" />
                    <button className="button">
                        <span className="button-content">Agregar</span>
                    </button>
                </form>
                {gifts.length == 0 && <p className="message">No seas Grinch y agregate un regalo! </p>}
                {gifts.length > 0 && 
                    <button className="button deleteAllButton" onClick={deleteAllGifts}>
                        <span className="button-content">Eliminar todos</span>
                    </button>
                }
            </section>
            {isOpen.repeatedModal && 
                <Modal>
                    <h1>No podes ingresár el mismo regalo dos veces. Intentalo nuevamente!</h1>
                    <button className="button">
                        <span className="button-content" onClick={toggle}>Aceptar</span>
                    </button>
                </Modal>
            }
        </main>
    )
}
```

useGift.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useModal } from "./useModal";

export const useGifts=()=>{
    const [gifts, setGifts]=useState([]);
    const {setIsOpen, isOpen}=useModal();

    const addGift=(el)=>{
        if (!gifts.some(gift=>el==gift) || gifts.length===0){
            const newGiftList=[...gifts, el];
            setGifts(newGiftList);
        } else {
            setIsOpen({
                repeatedModal:true
            })
        }
    }

    const deleteGift=(el)=>{
        const newGiftList=structuredClone(gifts);
        const i=newGiftList.indexOf(el);
        newGiftList.splice(i,1);
        setGifts(newGiftList);
    }

    const deleteAllGifts=()=>{
        setGifts([]);
    }
    
    return {gifts, addGift, deleteGift, deleteAllGifts}
}
```

useModal.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const useModal=()=>{
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen]=useState({
        repeatedModal:false
    });

    return {isOpen, setIsOpen}
}
```

Como podrán observar, el toggle del modal no está desarrollado por el solo hecho de que estoy trabado hace horas en poder mostrar el contenido. Si me pueden ayudar sería genial, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Bueno en `App` tienes `const {isOpen, toggle}=useModal();` y luego en `useGifts` parece que lo tienes al revés `const {setIsOpen, isOpen}=useModal();`

Comment: Hola @g.4, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder! Me di cuenta hoy cuando volvi a encarar el proyecto de esto, pero sin embargo al modificarlo sigue todo igual. Voy a encarar la creacion del modal desde 0 de nuevo a ver si puedo identificar el problema.

Comment: Ok ¿Cuando se debe renderizar el modal y cuando no? vamos por partes

Comment: Gracias @g.4 por la ayuda. Logré arreglarlo ayer, el modal se debia ejecutar cuando el un input se encuentre en blanco y el problema estaba justamente en la validación de esa condición. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Que bien, recuerda que puedes compartir tu solución respondiendo la pregunta y ganar tus primeros puntos, saludos